# Regarding scanner class

Tags: java

I am currently using StringTokennizer class to split a String into different token as by defined delimiter..

```
public class App {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        String str = "This is String , split by StringTokenizer, created by Neera";  
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);  


        System.out.println("---- Split by comma ',' ------");  
        StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");  

        while (st2.hasMoreElements()) {  
            System.out.println(st2.nextElement());  
        }  
    }  
}
```

My query is that can same thing can also be achieved through scanner class also ...!! Is it the right approach to use the scanner class since I was reading The Scanner class allows you to tokenize data from within a loop, which allows you to stop whenever you want to... I have tried the following thing, but it doesn't work ...please advise me ..!!!

```
public class App1 {  

    public static void main(String[] args)    
    {  
        Scanner scanner =  new Scanner("This is String , split by StringTokenizer, created by Neera").useDelimiter(", ");    

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) { 
            System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: scanner.useDelimiter(";");

read code in question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060843/regarding-arraylist/10060894

Answer (score 0):

Use [`scanner.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) to return the next token instead of [`scanner.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29), which returns the next full line (and your input only has one). And of course you'll want to use `hasNext()` in your `while` instead of `hasNextLine()`.

**In response to your comment:**

Your code has a syntax mistake, which I originally took for a typo and corrected in the question. You're writing:

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) ;
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
```

Which properly formatted should tell you what's really happening:

```
while (scanner.hasNext())
    ; // empty statement
System.out.println(scanner.next());
```

It should be:

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot..I have followed your advise below is the code still not getting the result, please advise me if any further changes are required..!! public class App1 {
 
 public static void main(String[] args)  
    {
 
  Scanner scanner =  new Scanner("This is String ,split by StringTokenizer,created by Neera").useDelimiter(", ");   
 
     while (scanner.hasNext())  ;
     System.out.println(scanner.next());
     
     //String line = scanner.next();
     //System.out.println(line);
 }  

}

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot, it working but the output that I am getting is...on console is... This is String ,split by StringTokenizer,created by Neera , instead it should be tokenize  on delimeter(,)..please advise me what thing is missing..!!..here is the piece of code..
public class App1 {
 
 public static void main(String[] args)  
    {
   Scanner scanner =  new Scanner("This is String ,split by StringTokenizer,created by saral").useDelimiter(", "); 
  while (scanner.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(scanner.next());}}}

Comment: @Neera - You have more typos. I'm not going to tell you what they are - it'll help you learn by figuring them out on your own.